# Error when looking up Context in Java Tomcat application when using multiple WARs

Tags: java, kotlin, tomcat

I have a .war that works just fine, with the following code to look up the JDBC resource:

```kotlin
if (envContext == null) {
    envContext = InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env") as Context
}

ds = envContext?.lookup("jdbc/myDS") as DataSource
```

This .war is defined as `ROOT.war` in the webapps folder.

If I duplicate this .war and put it under `webapps/foo/ROOT.xml` and properly configure `server.xml` as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
  <Service name="Catalina2">
    <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8553" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/foo"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

When I access `http://localhost:8080`, it works just fine, but if I try to access the second .war, at `http://localhost:8181` I get the following exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at br.com.simpli.sql.AbstractConPipe.<init>(AbstractConPipe.kt:24) --> this is where the code provided above is, more specifically inside the 'if'
```

I don't know much about how context lookup works, so I'm at a loss to what the problem is and how to fix it

My goal is to have two separate .wars accessible from the same url but different ports. Both .wars have a JDBC connection to a database defined in `META-INF/context.xml`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, it does! It was the name of the `Engine`. Thank you so much!